# How to configure heritrix to log all encountered URLs including those which are filtered / not to crawl?

Tags: java

I'm using heritrix 3.1.1-snapshot to crawl / archive some website contents, I need to log all urls encountered in every page it processes, including those urls which are (configured) not to be crawled.

I've been searching for long time and havent gotten positive results :( hope can get some helps here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://crawler.archive.org/articles/user_manual/config.html section 6.3.1.4 seems to answer your question.